# Prime Generator compiling and executing in IntelliJ;NZEC error in SPOJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to solve the Prime Generator problem on SPOJ using the code below

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Prime
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader nx = new BufferedReader(reader);

        int t; //t is the number of test cases
        int n1;
        int n2;// n1 and n2 and the smaller and larger number b/w which we      have to find all the primes

        System.out.println("Enter the number of test cases");
        t = Integer.parseInt(nx.readLine());

        if(t<=0)
        {
            return;
        }

        int i = 0;
        do
        {


            System.out.println("Enter the first number");
            n1 = Integer.parseInt(nx.readLine().trim());



            if(n1<0)
            {
                return;
            }

            if(n1<0)
            {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter the second number");
            n2 = Integer.parseInt(nx.readLine().trim());
            if(n2<0)
            {
                return;
            }


            int a;
            int b;


            for(a = n1; a <= n2; a++)
            {
                for(b = 2; b < a; b++)
                {
                    int quot = a%b;
                    if(quot == 0){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(a == b)
                {
                    System.out.println(" "+a);

                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }while(i < t);

    }
}
```

I apologize for the poorly indented code and the fact that the class declaration seems to have leaked out of the area meant for adding code but I haven't written Java in 4 years. I have been stuck on this problem since yesterday night and I can't get it to work in SPOJ even though it works perfectly in IntelliJ

[code running as it should in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuIP3.jpg)

But when I run the same code in SPOJ I get this

[SPOJ output](http://ideone.com/9buJhD)

I Googled the error message and tried to use try catch to solve the problem without success. Some people who got similar errors were advised to use the trim() function in parseInt() to remove whitespace but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: Notice, that you only have to try divisors up to the square root of the number you want to prove prime.

Answer (score 0):

In line 18 you try to convert a `null` string to a number. The string is `null` because there is no input available. From the documentation of `readLine()`:

> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Note also the "Standard input is empty" in the screenshot.

To summarize: there is nothing wrong with the program, you just don't provide any input data.

Comment: Wait but that doesn't explain why my code works in the IDE when I _do_ provide variables for the program to process..

Comment: When you test with the IDE the stdin stream is connected to the console. Therefore the program will wait for your input.